# Bhu-mandala system

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, cosmology, astronomy

*Bhagavata Purana*'s 5th Canto describes the Bhu-mandala planetary system. **Is the Bhu-mandala system THIS Earth (i.e. the planet in which I am writing this question), or is it a different planet located somewhere else in this universe?** The reason I ask this is because:

(1) The Earth does not contain oceans of milk, wine, sugarcane juice, etc

(2) Bhu-mandala has 7 islands, but the Earth does not (because Europe and Asia are technically not separate islands)

(3) The sizes of many mountains are just to long (several 1000s of yoganas)

Comment: You may want to have a look at : [What is the kanya region of bharatavarsha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46267/20129). As per the description in the Puranas, *bharata khanda can be taken as greater India* and *bharatavarsha, the current known earth* divided into 9 parts, not islands (which matches with the fact that 4 yugas are seen everywhere and salt water everywhere). Meaning it’s probable science hasn’t discovered other parts of bhu mandala yet. Further except for bharatavarsha (known earth), in other dvipas it is bhoga bhumi people live for 10,000 years etc.