# Is there a way to tie India to Bharata that would not work all all large landmasses?

Tags: vishnu

In the responses to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49896/is-bharatavarsha-the-entire-planet-or-only-indian-subcontinent), examples use features to determine Bharata. The issue is the only landmarks I know that determine it being India are two mountain ranges and an island off to sea. The issue is this is true of every large landmass. Is there anything tieing India to Bharata?

The thing is directions like north do not help, because the Himalayas are also how we decide what direction to call north from the text. If the scriptures were revealed to another landmass they will change which direction they think to correspond with which Sanskrit word.

Comment: what do you mean by tieing? do u mean any other physical features with which we can relate india to bharat ?

Comment: @Raghav yes. What are they?

Comment: I would have to see