# Who are adhikara(eligible) to read Manusmriti?

Tags: scripture, manu-smriti

In sanathan dharma, there is a concept called 'adhikara nirnayam'. It says about who all are eligible to read or recite or hear a particular scripture or stotra etc.,

Most of the scriptures mention the qualities needed for a person to read it.

Is there any such eligibility criteria for reading Manusmrithi?

Answer (score 2):

The last verse of the extant version of Manu Smriti says:

> 12.126. A twice-born man who recites these Institutes, revealed by Manu, will be always virtuous in conduct, and will reach whatever
> condition he desires.

This hints that only twice born persons are qualified to recite/read Manu Smriti.

Vyasa Smriti, however, explicitly states that only Dvijas, who wear the sacred thread, are qualified to read any Smritis.

> Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas are called the twice-born. Their
> first births take place when they are delivered of their mother's womb
> ; their second, when they duly accept the Gayatri Mantra from their
> preceptors (21).
>
> **Thus made twice-born, and free from all other faults, they become entitled to study the Vedas, Smritis and Puranas (22).**
>
> *(Chapter 1, Verses 21 and 22)*

Answer (score 1):

Quoting verses from Manusmriti -

> 1.102 - For the knowledge of deeds of brahmin and other varnas , the wise Manu , son of Brahma , has created this Manusmriti shastra.
>
> 1.103 - A learned brahmin should study this shastra diligently and preach it well to disciples.A person of any other varna should not preach it .
>
> 2.16 - From conception to funeral , for whom the sacraments have been prescribed , are entitled to this shastra

and as Rickross pointed out in [his answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49980/20129):

> 12.126 - The dvija who reads Manu-composed scripture propounded by Bhrigu , remains ethical and attains whatever state he desires.

so it is clear only brahmins are allowed to recite and preach manusmriti , while kshtriyas and vaishyas can read it .

However Dr. Surendra Kumar in Vishhudh Manusmriti declares all 4 verses as interpolated.

For 1.102 and 1.103  - https://archive.org/details/dr.surendrakumar/page/n277/mode/2up?view=theater

For 2.16 (in his book 2.16 is actually 1.135) - https://archive.org/details/dr.surendrakumar/page/n299/mode/2up?view=theater

For 12.126 https://archive.org/details/dr.surendrakumar/page/n1195/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: **while kshtriyas and vaishyas can read it** where it is given?

Comment: @hanugm in ganganath jha 's notes https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145552.html see at bottom of page

Comment: @hanugm I have edited my answer , 12.126 says all 3 varnas can read it

Comment: 12.126 was already given in my answer so there is no use of adding it to your answer @Raghav

Comment: @Rickross I didn't notice it , when I noticed it , I suggested edit because translation you gave is wrong. Now since you are not changing translation , so I had to add correct translation.

Comment: @Adiyarkku it would be nicer if you won't make false statements against me , here are your 2 false statements - 1) I don't know what s.bhagavatam answer you are. talking about  2)https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49896/is-bharatavarsha-the-entire-planet-or-only-indian-subcontinent/49900#49900 and finally , I will mention in my answer that rickross pointed out 12.126 , but I wont revert edit since rickross provided wrong translation , and I don't tolerate wrong info and knowledge

Comment: @Adiyarkku also by "notice" I meant that I  didn't see rickross 's answer , when I saw it , I found fault , I suggested edit , rickross rejected it , so I had too include that verse , so I didn't deliberately added that verse to look smart or knowledgable

Comment: There is no wrong translation given in my answer. You were trying to change recite to read which IMO is absolutely unnecessary @Raghav Also the translation is not mine it's part of the blockquote. We should not make changes there.

Comment: @Adiyarkku okayy , I will take care in future from now on

Comment: @Rickross both ganganath jha and dr surendra kumar have translated it as read  and not recite  , is ur translation from https://archive.org/details/ManuSmriti_201601/page/n273/mode/2up?view=theater ?

Comment: What is the difference between reading and reciting in this context? If you are reading something so that others can't hear then you are just reciting it in mind. @Raghav